# Sitecore Children of Datasource

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I am applying a datasource to a sublayout and obtaining the values of its children as follows:

```
Sitecore.Collections.ChildList childItems;

if (Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.DataSource) != null)
{
    childItems = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.DataSource).GetChildren();
}
else
{
    litDataSourceError.Text += "You need to set a datasource";
}

foreach (Item item in childItems)
{
    litDataSourceError.Text += "<h2>" + item.Fields["Title"].Value + "</h2>";
}
```

This is working as expected however these items also have children which I would like to output.

So my question is how to look down a further node within my ForEach to obtain the Childrens Children - there will only be these 2 levels of structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the same as you did for your datasource (fetch the children of the Sitecore Item):

```cs
foreach (Item item in childItems)
{
    litDataSourceError.Text += "<h2>" + item.Fields["Title"].Value + "</h2>";
    foreach (Item child in item.GetChildren())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you for your suggestion I will take that approach.